# Return Rows or Each Object from JSON Response with Latest Date using Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have JSON response from GET request in the format shown below. I want to filter and show on entries with Latest Date(Updated Date). There are multiple entries with same 'PK'. In that case I only want to show one with the last date. I want to have a filter function that provides such result. The code is in react. I am trying to filter that out in the reducer itself before passing down the component.

**My Action :**

```
export const trackingInfoFetchDataSuccess = trackingId => {
  return {
    type: TRACKINGINFO_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
    payload: trackingId
  };
}
```

**// Fetch Function**

```
export const trackingInfoFetchData= url => {
   return (dispatch) => {
       dispatch(trackingInfoIsLoading(true));
       const myData = myObject;
        fetch(url)
       .then((response) => {
           if (!response.ok) {
               throw Error(response.statusText);
           }
           dispatch(trackingInfoIsLoading(false));
           console.log(response);
           return response;
       })
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((items) => dispatch(trackingInfoFetchDataSuccess(items)))
       .catch(() => dispatch(trackingInfoHasErrored(true)));
   };
}
```

**My Reducer:**

```
export function trackingInformation(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TRACKINGINFO_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
       //Map or any filtering needs to be added here
            return action.payload;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**JSON Response**

```
[
    {
        "Pk" : "20",
        "CustomerPk" : "2juuxvk9f7zpxysapmqh3w2sh4hwhe4r",
        "TrackingId" : "Cancel: Recreated Account",
        "Comments" : "test",
        "ByRep" : "bsahoo",
        "Created" : "2014-01-16 11:59:00",
        "Updated" : "2014-01-16 11:59:02",
        "ExternalRef1" : null,
        "ExternalRef2" : null,
        "ExternalRef3" : null,
        "ExternalData" : null
    },
    {
        "Pk" : "21",
        "CustomerPk" : "49qh2tti5ddsev9a2536g5cxnw4pdj96",
        "TrackingId" : "ExternalPartner: Stream",
        "Comments" : "From Unit Test",
        "ByRep" : "Unit Test",
        "Created" : "2017-09-28 13:28:42",
        "Updated" : "2017-09-28 20:28:42",
        "ExternalRef1" : "value1",
        "ExternalRef2" : "value2",
        "ExternalRef3" : "value3",
        "ExternalData" : "Value 5"
    },
    {
        "Pk" : "21",
        "CustomerPk" : "hkerfq55nmvsxiv2kwebx9ksek7xv648",
        "TrackingId" : "Cancel: Recreated Account",
        "Comments" : "test",
        "ByRep" : "mageshwari",
        "Created" : "2013-11-14 14:15:49",
        "Updated" : "2013-11-14 14:15:51",
        "ExternalRef1" : null,
        "ExternalRef2" : null,
        "ExternalRef3" : null,
        "ExternalData" : null
    },
    {
        "Pk" : "22",
        "CustomerPk" : "5iin3cinsxawg3paya3zdsjq8bwnfw97",
        "TrackingId" : "Cancel: Call Quality",
        "Comments" : "Unit Test",
        "ByRep" : "system",
        "Created" : "2017-11-28 22:59:43",
        "Updated" : "2017-11-29 06:59:43",
        "ExternalRef1" : null,
        "ExternalRef2" : null,
        "ExternalRef3" : null,
        "ExternalData" : null
    },
    {
        "Pk" : "23",
        "CustomerPk" : "49qh2tti5ddsev9a2536g5cxnw4pdj96",
        "TrackingId" : "ExternalPartner: Stream",
        "Comments" : "From Unit Test",
        "ByRep" : "Unit Test",
        "Created" : "2017-09-22 04:47:46",
        "Updated" : "2017-09-22 11:47:46",
        "ExternalRef1" : "value1",
        "ExternalRef2" : "value2",
        "ExternalRef3" : "value3",
        "ExternalData" : "Value 5"
    },
    {
        "Pk" : "22",
        "CustomerPk" : "z9tcpsc7im4a3av5dw3hey8eemzr4pk4",
        "TrackingId" : "Cancel: Call Quality",
        "Comments" : "Unit Test",
        "ByRep" : "system",
        "Created" : "2017-07-21 17:17:05",
        "Updated" : "2017-07-22 00:15:33",
        "ExternalRef1" : null,
        "ExternalRef2" : null,
        "ExternalRef3" : null,
        "ExternalData" : null
    },
    {
        "Pk" : "22",
        "CustomerPk" : "49qh2tti5ddsev9a2536g5cxnw4pdj96",
        "TrackingId" : "ExternalPartner: Stream",
        "Comments" : "From Unit Test",
        "ByRep" : "Unit Test",
        "Created" : "2017-08-28 11:51:53",
        "Updated" : "2017-08-28 18:51:54",
        "ExternalRef1" : "value1",
        "ExternalRef2" : "value2",
        "ExternalRef3" : "value3",
        "ExternalData" : "Value 5"
    }]
```

The JSON key is bit modified to provide just an example of what I am trying to achive

Once the data is filtered, I only show the entries with latest date in the table instead of showing all the entries from JSON response into the table.

I am using React-Bootstrap-table for representation.

Right now I am showing whole JSON in the table.

Comment: Sorry, what is the problem in this code?

Comment: Do you only want to show entries with the latest date _per Pk_? Or across the entire data set?

Comment: I want to show the entries with the latest date per PK across the entire data set.

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
              if(results[i].TrackingId === results[i+1].TrackingId) {
                console.log('records', results[i]);
              }
          } I am trying something like this. Not sure whether filter or map function would work or not